# updateDisplayList on List SelectionChanged

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mxml

I have a class named AdvancedPanel, with buttons in header, which inherits Panel class, and AdvancedPanelSkin which does the PanelSkin class.
I have a List inside my AdvancedPanel and I want to enable a button when an item is selected on the list.

I have put the functioning to handle the enabling and disabling inside my overridden updateDisplayList() in child skin class, but it doesn't get called when I put invalidateDisplayList() call in List's changeHandler.
Here is the relative part of my code:

```
//AdvancedPanelSkin.as
//..
override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void
{
    super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
    addBtn.enabled = _hostComponent_.addButtonEnabled;
    removeBtn.enabled = _hostComponent_.removeButtonEnabled;  
}
//..
```

and

```
//form.mxml
//..
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        //...
        protected function list_changeHandler(event:IndexChangeEvent):void
        {
            panel.invalidateDisplayList(); // <- It doesn't call updateDisplayList() on AdvancedPanelSkin
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<components:AdvancedPanel id="panel" addButtonEnabled="true" removeButtonEnabled="{list.selectedIndex != -1}">
    <s:List id="list"
        //..
        change="list_changeHandler(event)"
    </s:List>   
</components:AdvancedPanel>
//..
```

Did I miss something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wondering why you've chosen to handle the logic for the buttons from within the skin. Why not just move that functionality into the AdvancedPanel Class?

Comment: I was a bit lazy and novice to create a seperate handler in component class. Now I have 2 handlers for 2 different work, and it works how I wanted.
Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invalidating display list of panel does not cause invalidating display list of its skin. Ideologically correct is to control skin from host component via **skin parts** other than component from its skin. So add the buttons to your panel as skin parts and override `updateDisplayList` of the Panel, not of its skin.

**AdvancedPanel.as**

```
[SkinPart]
public var addBtn:Button;
[SkinPart]
public var removeBtn:Button;

override public function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void {
        addBtn.enabled = ...;
        removeBtn.enabled = ...;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it does work. But for the sake of simplicity of question, I shortened my problem. The real problem is,
I have multi-level inheritance as
Panel -> AdvancedPanel -> AdvancedPanelWithButtons
I have created a header(HGroup) in AdvancedPanel, and I want to add buttons to this header in AdvancedPanelWithButtons. When I handle updateDisplayList in skin class, it appears normal. But when I do it in panel class, the buttons appear below the header.
I am new to flex and not sure whether setting negative top margin is a good manner. Can I directly add buttons to groups of parent class?

Comment: Nevermind, found the solution. I put an updateDisplayList in both the classes, component class handling the enabling/disabling and skin class everything else. Now it works as I wanted.
Thanks!